# Base for Y topology

Tags: general-topology

Be $X$ a topological space, $B$ a base of open for $X$ and $Y \subseteq X$. Prove that $B_Y = \{U \cap Y : U \in B\}$ is an open base for $Y$ (considering, about $Y$ , the subspace topology).

Be $A\in \tau_{Y}$, we need to show that there is a $U_i\cap Y$ such as $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i\cap Y)$. In fact if $\mathcal{B}$ is an open base for $X$ then for all open $U\in \tau_{X}$ there is a collection of open $B_i\subset \mathcal{B}$ such as $U=\cup_{i\in I} B_i$. Thus, $U_i \in B$. How can I show $Y\cap B_i\in B_Y$?

Comment: $Y\cap B_i\in B_Y$ by definition: $B_Y=\{Y\cap U:U\in B\}$, and $B_i\in B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it's correct what I did, just say it's by definition?

Comment: You need to say it a little differently, but you have all of the pieces. I’ll write an answer to explain that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! I wanted to using this base definition, $B$ is a basis if every element of the topology can be written as joining elements of $B$. And not with dots.

Answer (score 1):

Because the $B_i$ are from $\mathcal{B}$, $B_i \cap Y \in \mathcal{B}_Y$ by definition of that collection.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you have all of the pieces, but you need to put them together a bit more clearly.

If $A\in\tau_Y$, there is a $U\in\tau$ such that $A=U\cap Y$. $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$, so there is a family $\{B_i:i\in I\}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ such that $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$, and therefore

$$A=U\cap Y=\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)\cap Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}(B_i\cap Y)\,.$$

By definition $B_i\cap Y\in\mathcal{B}_Y$ for each $i\in I$, so we’ve shown that $A$ is the union of members of $\mathcal{B}_Y$. $U$ was an arbitrary element of $\tau_Y$, so

- every open set in $Y$ is the union of members of $\mathcal{B}_Y$.

Finally, $\mathcal{B}_Y\subseteq\tau_Y$, so

- every union of members of $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is open in $Y$.

These two points together show that $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is a base for $\tau_Y$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!It helped me a lot

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: You’re welcome!

Comment: You take a question from me? When you say: $B$  is a base for $Y$. Is that correct? It wouldn't be: $B$  is a base for $X$

Comment: Is there such a property? If $B$ is a base for $X$ (topological space) then $B$ is a base for $Y$, $Y \subset X$?

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: I’m sorry: that was a typo. It should have been $X$; I’ve fixed it now.

Comment: Great. Imagine, rest assured. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can I conclude that if $X$ is a topological space that checks the second enumerability axiom, then all $X$ subspace also checks it.

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: That’s an immediate consequence of the result here. If $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, so is $\mathcal{B}_Y$.

Comment: But why would it be? Because of the Y-induced topology? Or doesn't it even have to be subspace-induced topology?

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: You proved that $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is a base for $Y$, and the countability of $\mathcal{B}_Y$ has nothing to do with topology. If $X$ is any set, $Y$ is a subset of $X$, and $\mathscr{A}$ is any countable family of subsets $X$, then $\{A\cap Y:A\in\mathscr{A}\}$ is countable.